# How to do read() efficiently with reasonable buffer size, yet return early on a short read

Tags: python

We are writing a class that calls read on an io object, likely (but not necessarily) a file or a pipe. That stream contains a large number of small binary messages of format (length, blob), not fixed length, but in the order of 100 bytes.

The two obvious options are along the lines of

```
while True:
   length = unpack(f.read(4))
   blob = read(length)
```

which works fine, but is slow or:

```
while True:
   buffer = f.read(8192)
   for blob in unpack_buffer(blob):
       ...
   # handle the remainder
```

Which is fast, but when reading from a pipe in live streaming, will not return until there's 8K of data there, so not good for latency on sporadic input.

We have considered non-blocking reads, but that path is problematic is there isn't always an fd, and we're also reluctant to mess with the file object's params on a file object passed in from the user.

Is there some way to make read() return a partial buffer < 8192 bytes as soon as some data is present? I believe the underlying Unix read() syscall does this, but not fread().

Comment: I think that what you really want is a BufferedReader, which essentially does this: read whatever's available from the underlying source into a buffer in order to make small reads more efficient. If f is a BufferedReader then is the first option still slow?

Comment: So this:

    while True:
        buf = sys.stdin.buffer.read(8192)
        if not buf:
            sys.exit(0)

takes 2.6 seconds in 100 byte blocks, and 0.4 seconds in 8192 byte blocks (from pagecache). Not spectacular, but definitely somewhat slower.

Comment: How much are you reading in your example? That's quite a bit slower. Kind of curious why, though, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: About 1TB out of pagecache. I found a big dir of files and just did cat * | time script.py a few times in a row